# Variable as a column name in data frame

Tags: r

Is there any way to use string stored in variable as a column name in a new data frame? The expected result should be:

```
col.name <- 'col1'
df <- data.frame(col.name=1:4)
print(df)

# Real output
  col.name
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4

# Expected output
  col1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
```

I'm aware that I can create data frame and then use *names()* to rename column or use *df[, col.name]* for existing object, but I'd like to know if there is any other solution which could be used during creating data frame.

Comment: `data.frame(col1 = 1:4)` will give you the "Expected output"

Comment: @Jeff but he wants to pass `"col1"` from a variable

Comment: By the way, I've flagged this question to be moved to Stack Overflow, since it's about programming in R and not about statistics.

Comment: oh yes, sorry I misread, your answer covers everything in that case (+1)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You cannot pass a variable into the name of an argument like that.

Instead what you can do is:

```
df <- data.frame(placeholder_name = 1:4)
names(df)[names(df) == "placeholder_name"] <- col.name
```

or use the default name of `"V1"`:

```
df <- data.frame(1:4)
names(df)[names(df) == "V1"] <- col.name
```

or assign by position:

```
df <- data.frame(1:4)
names(df)[1] <- col.name
```

or if you only have one column just replace the entire `names` attribute:

```
df <- data.frame(1:4)
names(df) <- col.name
```

There's also the `set_names` function in the `magrittr` package that you can use to do this last solution in one step:

```
library(magrittr)
df <- set_names(data.frame(1:4), col.name)
```

But `set_names` is just an alias for:

```
df <- `names<-`(data.frame(1:4), col.name)
```

which is part of base R. Figuring out why this expression works and makes sense will be a good exercise.

Comment: Also, there is the `setNames` from `base R`

Answer (score 6):

In addition to ssdecontrol's answer, there is a second option.

You're looking for `mget`. First assign the name to a variable, then the value to the variable that you have previously assigned.  After that, `mget` will evaluate the string and pass it to data.frame.

```
assign("col.name", "col1")
assign(paste(col.name), 1:4)

df <- data.frame(mget(col.name))
print(df)
  col1
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you do this, but:

```
col.name <- 'col1'
eval(parse(text=paste0('data.frame(', col.name, '=1:4)')))
```

Comment: This indeed is a very bad way to do it. Parsing arbitrary text values is dangerous and should be avoided.