# name a df column from a character string contained in a list

Tags: r

If I have the example list `Names`

```
Names <- list(A = c("one", "two", "three"),
              B = c("three", "four", "five"))
```

Is it then possible to create a column heading using one of the strings contained in the list? For example, the code below is trying to create a column named `One` by indexing `Names[[1]][1]` but clearly does not work.

```
data.frame(Names[[1]][1] = rep(5, 5))
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I tried to wrap with `as.character()` but am still searching for solutions. The real data is being implemented within a loop and requires on the `Names` index. The desired out come is shown below.

```
data.frame(One = rep(5, 5))
```

Comment: Maybe with this. `setNames(data.frame(rep(5, 5)), Names[[1]][1])` ??

Comment: Seems to work well and can be expanded for multiple new columns. nice. post as an answer...?

Comment: At first, I thought this is a duplicate but couldn't find an appropriate question, hence answering it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083351/variable-as-a-column-name-in-data-frame or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531868/how-to-rename-a-single-column-in-a-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setnames` to assign column names from a variable to a dataframe :

```
setNames(data.frame(rep(5, 5)), Names[[1]][1]) 

#  one
#1   5
#2   5
#3   5
#4   5
#5   5
```

which definitely can be used for multiple columns as well.